# Cannot scrape the table for href links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the href links from the table which I later need to click one by one to access the data inside each links. But I cannot figure out a way to do it. I have tried find_all and have been getting "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s' error.

HTML: (Really long so this is a 1/10)

```
<thead>
<tr class="sctablehead">
<th>Academic Program</th>
<th>Departments</th>
<th>Academic Level</th>
<th>College</th>
<th>Online</th>
<th>Degree Type</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="even firstrow"><td><a href="/graduate/graduate-programs/master-accountancy/">Accountancy</a></td><td>Accounting</td><td>Graduate</td><td>BUS</td><td></td><td>MAC</td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td><a href="/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-business-administration/school-accounting-finance/bsba-in-accounting/">Accounting</a></td><td>Accounting</td><td>Undergraduate</td><td>BUS</td><td></td><td>BSB</td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td><a href="/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-business-administration/school-accounting-finance/accounting-minor/">Accounting</a></td><td>Accounting</td><td>Undergraduate</td><td>BUS</td><td></td><td>Minor</td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td><a href="/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-science-technology-engineering-mathematics/department-mathematics-statistics/actuarial-science-minor/">Actuarial Science</a></td><td>Mathematics, Economics, Finance</td><td>Undergraduate</td><td>STEM</td><td></td><td>Minor</td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td><a href="/graduate/graduate-programs/post-masters-adult-gero-acute-care-nurse-pract-certificate-program/">Adult Gerontology Acute Care Nurse Practitioner</a></td><td>Nursing</td><td>Graduate</td><td>HHS</td><td></td><td>PMC</td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td><a href="/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-business-administration/department-marketing/advertising-public-relations/">Advertising and Public Relations</a></td><td>Advertising</td><td>Undergraduate</td><td>BUS</td><td></td><td>BSB</td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td><a href="/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-business-administration/department-marketing/advertising-public-relations-minor/">Advertising Public Relations</a></td><td>Marketing</td><td>Undergraduate</td><td>BUS</td><td></td><td>Minor</td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td><a href="/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-health-human-services/aerospace-studies-program/">Aerospace Studies</a></td><td>Aerospace Studies</td><td>Undergraduate</td><td>HHS</td><td></td><td>Minor</td></tr>
<tr class="even"><td><a href="/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-liberal-arts-social-sciences-education/department-africana-studies-minor/">Africana Studies</a></td><td>Africana Studies</td><td>Undergraduate</td><td>BCLASSE</td><td></td><td>Minor</td></tr>
```

... And so on

My Code:

```
r = requests.get(driver.current_url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
programs_table = soup.find_all('table', {"class":"sc_sctable tbl_degrees sorttable"})

for tr in programs_table.find_all('tr class'):
    for a in tr.find_all('a'):
        print(a['href'])
```

Comment: For one this, `find_all('tr class')` should be `find_all('tr')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is found properly(as you have not provided the html for that..)
Then `ONLY`:-

```
r = requests.get(driver.current_url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
programs_table = soup.find_all('table', {"class":"sc_sctable tbl_degrees sorttable"})

for tr in programs_table.find_all('tr'):
    for a in tr.find_all('a'):
        print(a['href'])
```

In other words you can try `programs_table.find_all("tr")` instead of `programs_table.find_all("tr class")`

Because I get results after using this as follows:

````
/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-business-administration/school-accounting-finance/bsba-in-accounting/
/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-business-administration/school-accounting-finance/accounting-minor/
/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-science-technology-engineering-mathematics/department-mathematics-statistics/actuarial-science-minor/
/graduate/graduate-programs/post-masters-adult-gero-acute-care-nurse-pract-certificate-program/
/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-business-administration/department-marketing/advertising-public-relations/
/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-business-administration/department-marketing/advertising-public-relations-minor/
/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-health-human-services/aerospace-studies-program/```
````

Comment: I did find the table but I dont know if it is found properly! I have tried doing just tr insted of tr class but am still getting "in __getattr__ 'ResultSet object has no attribute '%s' " error. I have tried using find, find_all and findAll to search for the element.

Comment: If possible please provide html for table also.That can help maybe.

Comment: Sure here is the top portion of the table.  Thanks                                                            <table class="sc_sctable tbl_degrees sorttable" id="tbl_degrees">
<thead>
<tr class="sctablehead">
<th>Academic Program</th>
<th>Departments</th>
<th>Academic Level</th>
<th>College</th>
<th>Online</th>
<th>Degree Type</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="even firstrow"><td><a href="/graduate/graduate-programs/master-accountancy/">Accountancy</a></td><td>Accounting</td><td>Graduate</td><td>BUS</td><td></td><td>MAC</td></tr>

Comment: Here is the link to the full source code if it helps. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AnRQ6c3wgc1LCzar6yZnuXCg2cb_-1Lm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It works fine for me when I use find() instead of find_all() for getting table...

Comment: `programs_table = r.find('table', {"class":"sc_sctable tbl_degrees sorttable"})`


Works for me ...
Do I show a demo in repl?

Comment: https://repl.it/@Arnav17Sharma/Test#main.py run main.py and you can see...

Comment: Yess sir. Got it. Its working now. Thank you very much. I upvoted the comment but my low level wont make a difference I guess.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be using `find_all` to scrape one tag unless you really want it to be in a list. So, to get the table you should just to do:

```
programs_table = soup.find('table', class_="sc_sctable")
```

Now to get inner `<a>` tags with `href` links, you can scrape `<td>` tags which have inner `<a>` tag:

```
tags_with_href = programs_table.tbody.find_all('td')
links = [each_tag.a['href'] for each_tag in tags_with_href if each_tag.a]
# -> ['/graduate/graduate-programs/master-accountancy/', ... ]
```

If you want to have absolute url instead of relative one, you can define `base_url` and add each relative urls to it:

```
base_url = '<base_url_of_website>'
links = [base_url + link for link in links]
```